# Index datatime in a dateframe from a list of datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, time

First of all, I did this function that returns one date frame but I wanna use in a list of dates and then concatenate them in one data frame with the index being the date time stamp that is in the list

```
lista = [datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 13, 0, 0)]
```

This is my function:

```
def min_f(yyear,mmonth,dday):

    a_00_04 = int( df_output.loc[ (df_output.index > timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday)-timedelta(hours=1)))  &  (df_output.index <= timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,4)+timedelta(hours=2))) ].min() ) #.tolist()[0]#
    a_04_08 = int( df_output.loc[ (df_output.index > timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,4,00)-timedelta(hours=1)))  &  (df_output.index <= timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,8,00)+timedelta(hours=2))) ].min() )
    a_08_12 = int( df_output.loc[ (df_output.index > timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,8,00)-timedelta(hours=1)))  &  (df_output.index <= timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,12,00)+timedelta(hours=2))) ].min() )
    a_12_16 = int( df_output.loc[ (df_output.index > timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,12,00)-timedelta(hours=1)))  &  (df_output.index <= timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,16,00)+timedelta(hours=2))) ].min() )
    a_16_20 = int( df_output.loc[ (df_output.index > timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,16,00)-timedelta(hours=1)))  &  (df_output.index <= timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,20,00)+timedelta(hours=2))) ].min() )
    a_20_24 = int( df_output.loc[ (df_output.index > timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,20,00)-timedelta(hours=1)))  &  (df_output.index <= timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday+1,00,00)+timedelta(hours=2))) ].min() )

    d = {'00_04': [a_04_08], '04_08': [a_04_08], '08_12': [a_08_12], '12_16': [a_12_16],'20_24': [a_20_24]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    return df
```

Right now from one looks like this:

```
   00_04  04_08  08_12  12_16  20_24
0  21359  21359  10486   6747  14335
```

And I wanna to set it like this:

```
           00_04  04_08  08_12  12_16  20_24
2017-11-10  21359  21359  10486   6747  14335
```

But adding also the results from my list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not positive what you're going for, but maybe something like this:

```
def create_df(dl):
    idx = []
    cols = {
        '00_04': [],
        '04_08': [],
        '08_12': [],
        '12_16': [],
        '20_24': [],
    }

    for date in dl:
        col['00_04'].append(int( df_output.loc[ (df_output.index > timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday)-timedelta(hours=1)))  &  (df_output.index <= timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime(yyear,mmonth,dday,4)+timedelta(hours=2))) ].min() ))
        ...

        index.append(date)

    return pd.DataFrame(cols, index=idx)
```

It's hard to tell what you're going for here, but it seems you may be missing a `16-24` field as well?

Hope this helps.